# Redirecting piped command into a file in bash

Tags: bash, pipe, command-line-interface, io-redirection

I'm trying to do the following:

```
ping some.server.com | grep -Po '(?<=\=)[0-9].\.[0-9]' >> file.dat
```

i.e. I run a command (ping), grep part of the output and redirect the result of grep into a file to be inspected later. While the command itself works (i.e. the part before '>>'), nothing gets written into the file.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Did you wait long enough? Looks to me like a buffering issue (i.e., the file won't be written until you have, say, 4KB in stdout; interrupting with `^C` prematurely will not write the result also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `--line-buffered` argument.

```
ping some.server.com | grep --line-buffered -Po '(?<=\=)[0-9].\.[0-9]' >> file.dat
```